# My vue application throwing error `Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'` in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

I am having this problem

[image]

[image]

I tried to add something like this in vender.js

```
if (!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.contains = function (str, startIndex) {
        return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
    };
}
```

But still it is not working.
What can be the cause ?

IE version 11.0.9600

Comment: Please specify the IE version you're using. Also specify whether it's running in compatibility mode.

Comment: I have added IE version.

Comment: Did you try to console log String prototype before and after adding contains property, then compare them ? or just test : String.prototype.contains == undefined before and after

Comment: it looks like you might be missing a closing parenthesis on line 10 unless that's a screenshot problem

Comment: Install `babel-polyfill` as an npm package and import it write at the top of your main js file. E.g. `import 'babel-polyfill` or `require('babel-polyfill')`

Comment: Thanks @RuChernChong that's worked.

Comment: I will convert that to an answer and you can accept and close this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `babel-polyfill` as an npm package and import it right at the top of your main js file. E.g. `import 'babel-polyfill'` or `require('babel-polyfill')`